# parallel alignment

Tags: drawing, alignment, line-art

I had to do this in powerpoint but I'm wondering if there is an alternative program that does this well?I wanted to create a diagonal grid style of lines. It's actually a description of an alternative method of multiplication.

Normally when you want to duplicate a line you can constrain and duplicate (Ctrl+Shift+Alt etc.) it horizontal or vertical but I needed to be able to make it parallel with the ends aligning on a diagonal like a perspective. The lines weren't specifcially a grid as some gaps were needed so I can't just skew a drawing. But for understanding I needed to make a consistent group of lines appear equally spaced in one section but not another and have all lines aligned to a diagonal. Anyone know of a drawing program that does this?
[image]

Comment: Almost any vector app can do this.

Comment: Raster apps too.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you give an example. Photoshop for instance, doens't do anything like this. I'm talking about aligning the ends of the blue lines on their diagonals, by smart guide or quick duplication. (align to line? etc.) notice only a few lines are aligned correctly in this image (the top 2 horizontal*ish)

Comment: ...Why can't you make the blue lines longer / shorter as needed? All that I see needing to be done is expanding in some places and trimming / shortening in others. Am I missing something?

Comment: unfortunately in PowerPoint it's difficult as you don't get fine control. I'm not asking how to make the drawing better.